# iOS Drag and drop

Tags: ios, drag-and-drop

I would like to make an easy app - game with a letters.

I am searching for an example, how to drag an image and drop it to a position which belongs only to this image.

There will be for example a picture of apple on background and 5 UIImageView with letters A, P, P, L, E.  You take a letter A and bring it to the right UIImageView (which belongs only to the letter A - in another you can´t). Than letter L and so on ... until there is written apple.

I can drag and drop each letter everywhere on a screen (there exists a lot of tutorials :)).

**But I don´t know, how to drop for example letter A - to the right UIImageView who was made only for a letter A.**

Do you know about some tutorial or source code or example?

Thank you very much...

Answer (score 3):

There's a simple open-source framework for iOS called "iOS-DragAndDrop" that does exactly what you need.  You can define any UIView as a draggable view, and you can define specific views (including invisible ones) that that draggable view can be dropped into.

Check it out: [iOS-DragAndDrop on Github](http://github.com/brynbellomy/iOS-DragAndDrop)

There's documentation at that link as well.